# Can I use an angular component selector as an attribute for that component?

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, angular-components

For example,

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'editor', //Same as component input
      templateUrl: './editor.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./editor.component.scss']
    })
    export class Editor implements OnInit {
      @Input() editor: string; //Same name as selector
      @Input() color: string;
      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }
   }
```

HTML:
`<div editor="value" color="blue"></div>`

My experience until now is that this doesn't work. Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this work? Or if it's even possible?

Comment: Did you try `[editor]`?

Comment: that yould translate into <editor [editor]="val" [color]="valC"></editor>, and yes its possible

Comment: Yeah, I got it to work thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use property binding on your div tag.

```
 [editor]="value"
```

Answer (score 0):

it is possible, you should enclose your selector in square braces

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: '[editor]', //Same as component input
    template: `<span>Foo Bar template</span>`,
})
export class TryComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() editor: string; //Same name as selector
    @Input() color: string;
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.info(this.editor);
    }
}
```

then use like this

```
<div [editor]="'FooBarValue'" color="blue"></div>
```

or

```
<div [editor]="classProperty" color="blue"></div>
```